# How to get IEnumerable from IQueryable in such cases, where 2 queries are required in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have situation like this: in `LearningStatuses` table I have a composite primary key, made up of `CourseCode` and `UserID`.

`CourseCode` and `UserID` are also the PK of `Course` and `ApplicationUser` tables respectively.

The `LearningStatuses` table is basically working as a enroll table.
So if a user enroll in a course, his user ID and Course Code will be stored in this table.

Now I want to fetch all the enrolled courses of a particular user in his dashboard.

Firstly I'm looking for the `courseCode` that is there in the `learningSatatuses` table with his user ID, and storing it in a list of int.

Now I want the list of courses from the database, of those IDs as an `IEnumerable` to iterate over them in the view.

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    string currentUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    List<int> CoursesEnrolled = db.LearningStatuses 
                                  .Where(l => l.UserID == currentUserID)
                                  .Select(l => l.CourseCode)
                                  .ToList();

    List<Course> CoursesEnrolledCourse = new List<Course>();

    foreach (int item in CoursesEnrolled)
    {
        Course c = (Course)db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseCode == item);
        CoursesEnrolledCourse.Add(c);
    }

    return View();
}
```

During the 2nd step, I find myself unable to cast this `IQueryable` to a list anymore.

I've tried few other approaches too. but at the end of it I'm not able to get the desired `IEnumerable` of course objects for a particular user.

N.B: I have an Identity Framework user table. So my `UserID` is an alias of `ApplicationUserID`, that's a string.

What is the right approach to get the expected result.

Comment: That looks like a pretty basic use case. In a properly modeled DB with a navigation property for course, you should be able to do that in a single fetch.  Something like `var coursesForUser = db.LearningStatuses.Where(l => l.UserID == currentUserID).Select(ls => ls.Course).ToList();` No need for all those extra DB calls.

Comment: var courses = db.Courses.Where(x => CoursesEnrolled.Contains(x.CourseCode));   This is answer. The answer provided by Steve Geene will also work if you reference it under your model.